# Windows installation logs for QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, installation, windows, log

I want to deploy QGIS 3.4.7.1 to several Windows 7 x64 machines. It would be nice, if I could get the installation logs somehow.
I have tried to use /V 4 as parameter, and /O to define log file, but there is no result. Can somehow please send me a document about available CLI installation parameters, or suggest me what should I use?

Answer (score 2):

The logs are placed at installdir\postinstall.log. 
By default: c:\program files\QGIS 3.4\postinstall.log
You can change the installation directory with /D parameter.